# AngularJS: How to pass arguments/functions to a directive?

Tags: javascript, html, controller, scope, angularjs

Look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y85Ft/), what do I have to change, that the expressions in the template get evaluated using the arguments I defined in the HTML? The SAVE-button should call the `blabla()`-function of the controller, since I pass it?

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',[])
myApp.directive('editkeyvalue', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            accept: "expression"
        },
        template : '<div><label class="control-label">{{key}}</label>' +
        '<label class="control-label">{{key}}</label>' +
          '<input type="text" ng-model="value" />'+
        '<button type="button" x-ng-click="cancel()">CANCEL</button>' +
        '<button type="submit" x-ng-click="save()">SAVE</button></div>',

      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
        $scope.save= function() {
          $scope.accept();
        };
      }
    }
});
```

I do not really see through that. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can set two way data binding with `property: '='` as Roy suggests. So if you want both `key` and `value` bound to the local scope you would do

```
scope: {
    key: '=',
    value: '='
},
```

Since you are passing these values, you have access to them in your directive's controller. But in case you want to run a function in the context of the parent scope, which seems to be  what you want to do with the `accept` attribute, then you would need to tell angular like this

```
scope: {
    accept: "&"
}
```

Now, from your `save` method you could call the function passed via `accept`

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
    $scope.save= function() {      
        $scope.accept()
    };
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/y85Ft/7/)

Comment: Any way to pass a variable from the directive to the function passed to it?

Comment: Found the answer to my own question. You have to name the parameters involved.  Found answer here: http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=894

Answer (score 15):

```
scope: {
    accept: "&"
}
```

Use lowercase letters for function names, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Why does this kind of stuff come out only on Friday afternoons? Thanks, mate.

Comment: You don't need to use lowercase letters, just know that if you write it like 'acceptSomething' you will refer to it as 'accept-something' in markup

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note that you dont need the wrapping function save. Just call this in the template:

`'<button type="submit" x-ng-click="accept()">SAVE</button></div>',`

That transposes the function call and passes the parameters as expected.

This simplifies code and makes it a lot easier to read.