# AngularJS - Make a directive "scope-sensitive"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a page with 2 containers on it , each one contains images. I want to add some specific visual attributes and functionalities to these images. These specific stuff is similar in both depositories  but it is not the same. So i want to create **one** directive for 2 types of images , but i want it to behaviour a little bit differently depending on in what depository ( actually, scope ) image is placed. Checking for element's scope in directive's body:

```
studio.directive('orientable', function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              if(scope.id=="Depository1"){ 
              // give to element some specific behaviour
              }else if(scope.id=="Depository2"){ 
              // give to element another specific behaviour
              }
    }    
}
```

seems ugly to me.
I can't use passing arguments to a directive, because then image's tag will turn to unreadable and when there are many images it will be disaster . I do not want two directives because they will be basically same.
So i want one directive , but somehow it must be "polymorphic".
 Is it some kind of inheritance possible here? I think i'm missing something important in understanding of Angular' directives .

Comment: why not attributes that can be passed as parameteres to the directive? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725938/angularjs-how-to-pass-arguments-functions-to-a-directive

in any case, your directive should probably have `scope:true`. otherwise, two `orientable` will be sharing things

Comment: @EduardGamonal Then it will be too much DRY in my html code , and i think its bad for performance too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single directive to behave differently based on scope, then checking some scope property seems perfectly reasonable to me.

The closest I think you can come to polymorphism in Angular is to put shared things (data, functions, etc.) into a service, then inject that service into the places you want polymorphism (directives, controllers, other services, etc.).

Comment: Oh , i think i get it. I need to check a scope for some more global properties , like "isDragEnabled" and not for scope's "id" , so directive will stay more generic and not case-specific, right?

Comment: @Cherniv, yes, check for some property on the scope that would make sense for the directive.