# AngularJS directive - passing function as argument to "&" attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-directive

I know `angular directive` very deeply, and I'm trying to do something very simple, and I think it's not supported in angular.
I'm trying to pass a function as argument to the directive isolated scope (type `&`).
I just want to deliver the "`@`" scope values to the function implemented in my controller.
It seems like it's impossible to call the "`&`" scope attribute with arguments.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <testkeyvalue accept="blabla" key='keyA' value='valueA' />
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])
myApp.directive('testkeyvalue', function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            key: '@',
            value: '@',
            accept: "&"
        },
        template: '<div><label class="control-label">{{key}}</label><br/>' +
        '<label class="control-label">{{value}}</label>' ,



        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {

            var arr = ["key", "value", "accept"];
            for (var i = 0, cnt = arr.length; i < arr.length; i++)
            {

                scope.$watch(arr[i], function ()
                {
                    cnt--;
                    if (cnt <= 0)
                    {
                        fireaccept()
                    }
                });
            }

            var fireaccept = function ()
            {
                //This is the problem
                //I can't deliver this arguments to the "blabla" function im my controller
                scope.accept(scope.key, scope.value);
            }
        }
    };
});


myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window)
{
    $scope.blabla = function (key, val)
    {
        $window.alert("key:" + key + " val: " + val);
    };
});
```

Here is the full demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/chezih/y85Ft/401/

I've read this question: [AngularJS: How to pass arguments/functions to a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725938/angularjs-how-to-pass-arguments-functions-to-a-directive)
But it's not what I'm looking for, I just want to register the controller, to event that triggered from inside the directive (and the event can pass arguments).

There is any way to do this?

Comment: can you not use scope.$eval, you wont need to get the argument to pass them back...

Answer (score 3):

this is working like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/Pascalz/hr8zua7q/

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <testkeyvalue accept="blabla(key, val)" key='keyA' value='valueA' />
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])
myApp.directive('testkeyvalue', function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            key: '@',
            value: '@',
            accept: "&"
        },
        template: '<div><label class="control-label">{{key}}</label><br/>' +
        '<label class="control-label">{{value}}</label>' ,

        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            var arr = ["key", "value", "accept"];
            for (var i = 0, cnt = arr.length; i < arr.length; i++)
            {      
                scope.$watch(arr[i], function ()
                {
                    cnt--;
                    if (cnt <= 0)
                    {
                        fireaccept()
                    }
                });
            }

            var fireaccept = function ()
            {
                //This is the problem
                //I can't deliver this arguments to the "blabla" function im my controller
                scope.accept({key:scope.key, val:scope.value});
            }
        }
    };
});


myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window)
{
    $scope.blabla = function (key, val)
    {
        $window.alert("key:" + key + " val: " + val);
    };
});
```

Comment: You don't have to paste the full code, just the portion of the working code.

Comment: It's works, but all the develpoers that use this directive need to know to pass those values to accept attribute (it's make the directive API more complex).  there's any way to **pass** the function but not to call the function (likemy question)

Comment: Use `"="` instead of `"&"` to get a reference to a function.

Answer (score 0):

As Jussi Kosunen said in the comments, you can use the "=" operator instead of "&" to get access to a function as a variable in your isolate scope.

A minimal directive could look like this:

```
directive('exDir', function () {
    return {
        scope: {isolateScopeFunction: "=fun"},
        template: '<button ng-click="isolateScopeFunction(\'inside isolateScope\')">press</button>'
    };
});
```

and you would use it like this:

```
<div ex-dir fun="outerScopeFunctionName"></div>
```